# Insertar automáticamente un guión al escribir fechas

Tags: php, javascript, html

necesito insertar el carácter "-" al escribir una fecha en un input de tipo text. El "-" (guion alto), debe escribirse rápidamente al terminar de ingresar los dos primeros caracteres y los dos caracteres siguientes, es decir debería quedar así por ejemplo 10-12-2019. Literalmente quiero escribir 10122019 y que los "-" se agreguen solos, se que puede hacerse con JS, pero no tengo conocimiento, hasta ahora he armado algo así.

Pero me funciona solamente para agregar el primero "-" ¿Cómo hago para agregarlo también antes de que escriba el año?

```html
$(document).ready(Reportes);
    function Reportes(){
        var fg1 = true;
        $(document).on('keyup','[id=input1]',function(e){
            if($(this).val().length == 2 && fg1) {
                $(this).val($(this).val()+":");
                fg1 = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<form action="reporte.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 sclass">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="input1" type="text" name="fechainc" placeholder="Fecha inicio...">
          <br>
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" onchange="prueba" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha fin...">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="reportar">Generar</button>
        </form>
```

Muchas gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar javascript para validar de forma sencilla la máscara que necesitas:

```
<script>
function mascara(valor) {
  if (valor.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    return valor + '-';
  } else if (valor.match(/^\d{2}\-\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    return valor + '-';
  }
  return cadena;
}
</script>
<input name="fecha" type="text" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
    onkeyup="this.value = mascara(this.value)" maxlength="10">
```